# hide parts of form until certain fields are filled in

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Please help me with my code.  I'm trying to hide some fields until all other fields are filled in.

Here's my code:

HTML

```
<div id="group1">

        <label>Field 1:</label>
        <input type="text" class="field1"/><br/>
        <label>Field 2:</label>
        <input type="text" class="field2"/><br/>
        <label>Field 3:</label>
        <input type="text" class="field3"/><br/>

</div>

<div id="group2">

       <label>Field 4:</label>
       <input type="text" class="field4"/>

</div>
```

CSS

```
#group2 {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

JQuery

```
$(".field1",".field2",".field3").keyup(function () {
    if ($(".field1",".field2",".field3").val() != "") {
        $("#group2").css("visibility", "visible");
    } else {
        $("#group2").css("visibility", "hidden");
    }
});
```

Comment: Post your current code.

Comment: You saw the warning when you posted a link to jsFiddle without any code in your questions but you chose to try and circumvent the rule by highlighting text as code. Please always post your code in your question. A jsFiddle should be secondary. If jsFiddle is ever inaccessible, then without the code in your question, your question loses all value.

Comment: ok, i'll add the code

Comment: Well first I'd change `document.getElementById` for `$` and just add a `#` to the front of the search string, your using jquery, why not use it for everything (getting the value is just `.val()` instead of `.value`)? Why not put those parts of the form you want to hide into a divs with the same class but differant ID's and set them to hidden with CSS using that class then use Jquery to display them by selecting them via there IDs?

Comment: i was thinking of doing divs and placing them around the certain fields but I don't know coding that well.

Comment: just use ` display: none` in the CSS for that class element` and then set the class to `block` with jquery when you want to display the class. Take a look at this link : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp and http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp for info.

Comment: I just updated my question with the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, So I Looked in to your code and re-wrote it to be more flexible and allow the code to be used in other places (i.e other forms, pages, etc) I coded some utility functions, a Helper and included a regex filter for jquery.

The functions will work with an array of dom elements or a single element (so you can check for multiple fields or just the one)

the main thing that's different in the CSS is that the Class is used to hide ALL elements and it uses the ID of a specific element to un-hide it. In other words give all elements that you want to hide the `"hidden"` class and each element a unique ID then pass that ID to the helper's `unHideThis` argument to un-hide it. Pass to the helper dom elements you want to check for being blank to the helper function's `checkThis` argument.

jsfiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/vdxdvy7q/3/)

example html:

```
<div id="group1">

        <label>Field 1:</label>
        <input type="text" class="field1"/><br/>
        <label>Field 2:</label>
        <input type="text" class="field2"/><br/>
        <label>Field 3:</label>
        <input type="text" class="field3"/><br/>

</div>

<div class="hidden" id="part_1">

       <label>Field 4:</label>
       <input type="text" class="field4"/>

</div>
<div class="hidden" id="part_2">

       <label>Field 5:</label>
       <input type="text" class="field5"/><br>
       <label>Field 6:</label>
       <input type="text" class="field6"/>

</div>
```

example css:

```
.hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

JS code & Regex Filter:

```
//regex filter http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/
// vvv Allows the use of regex to search with vvv
jQuery.expr[':'].regex = function(elem, index, match) {
    var matchParams = match[3].split(','),
        validLabels = /^(data|css):/,
        attr = {
            method: matchParams[0].match(validLabels) ? 
                        matchParams[0].split(':')[0] : 'attr',
            property: matchParams.shift().replace(validLabels,'')
        },
        regexFlags = 'ig',
        regex = new RegExp(matchParams.join('').replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,''), regexFlags);
    return regex.test(jQuery(elem)[attr.method](attr.property));
}
// ^^^ Allows the use of regex to search with ^^^

//main JS 
$(document).ready(function() {
    fieldsInitial = $("input:regex(class, field[1-3])")
    fieldsPart1 = $("input:regex(class,field4)")


    checkAndUnHide(fieldsInitial,"#part_1")
    checkAndUnHide(fieldsPart1,"#part_2")

})

// vvv my js code, place this in separate file to use the functions vvv
//Helper Function
function checkAndUnHide ( checkThis,unHideThis) {
    checkThis.keyup(unHideThis, function(event){ 
        unHide(checkThis,event.data)
    }) 
}

//checks if the .val() of each element is blank or not
function allElementsFilled(arrayOfDomElements) {
return !(arrayOfDomElements.map(function () {
         return $(this).val()})
         .get()
         .some(function (element) { return element == ""})
        )
}

//will unhide element if check's .val() is not blank
function unHide(check, element) {
    if(typeof check !== 'string'){
        if (allElementsFilled(check)) {
            $(element).css("visibility", "visible")            
        }
    }
    else{
        if(check.val != ""){
            $(element).css("visibility", "visible")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try to do something like this:

```
$('#group1 > input[type="text"]').keyup(function () {
    if ($('.field1').val() !== '' && $('.field2').val() !== '' && $('.field3').val() !== '') {
        $('#group2').css('visibility', 'visible');
    } else {
        $('#group2').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    }
});
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Your comparison operator is wrong in your Jquery. It should be !== , not !=